# How to impelement ViewModelProvider.Factory?

Tags: java, android, viewmodel, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack

I wanted to access the **ViewModel** class (which extends AndroidViewModel) in the **onViewCreated** method of my Fragment. Below line of code should work as [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#implement) said. But it doesn't!

```
ProductListViewModel viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(ProductListViewModel.class);
```

Apparently, **ViewModelProvider** constructor has been changed recently. it needs a **ViewModelProvider.Factory** implementation as a second argument. Why a **ViewModelProvider.Factory** implementation is needed and How should do that?

Here is my Fragment class:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private HomeListAdapter homeListAdapter;

    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static HomeFragment newInstance() {
        return new HomeFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        homeListAdapter = new HomeListAdapter(getContext());

        RecyclerView homeRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rv_products);
        homeRecyclerView.setAdapter(homeListAdapter);
        homeRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        ProductListViewModel viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(ProductListViewModel.class);

        viewModel.getAllProducts().observe(this, new Observer<List<Product>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<Product> products) {
                homeListAdapter.setProducts(products);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And this is my ViewModel:

```
public class ProductListViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private ProductRepository mRepository;
    private LiveData<List<Product>> mAllProducts;

    public ProductListViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);

        mRepository = new ProductRepository(application);
        mAllProducts = mRepository.getAllProducts();
    }

    public LiveData<List<Product>> getAllProducts() {
        return mAllProducts;
    }

    public void insert(Product product) {
        mRepository.insert(product);
    }
}
```

Comment: Update to latest v2.2.0 of androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions library, you should be able to use ViewModelProvider without factory parameter which creates default factory for you. Its required to create instant which comes really handy when doing dependency injection using Dagger or Hilt. I would suggest to use Hilt which further removes boilerplate code for factory creation if you required one for testing purpose.

Comment: Since you're observing LiveData from within a Fragment, you should try switching the first parameter of your `observe()` statement to `getViewLifecycleOwner()` instead of using `this`.

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0):

Because the ViewModelProvider doesn't know how the ViewModel injects the constructor.

You have to implement interface

[ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory)

in kotlin:

```
class MyAndroidViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application)

class MyViewModelFactory(application: Application) :
    ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(application)

class MyActivity : Activity() {
    val viewModel = MyViewModelFactory(this.application).create(MyAndroidViewModel::class.java)
}
```

> AndroidViewModel provides application context which is problematic for
> unit testing. Unit tests should not deal with any of the Android
> lifecycle, such as context.